# Facing Difficulty While Login into postgreSQL through cmd in Windows 10

Tags: database, windows, postgresql, user-controls, postgresql-12

- I am new to postgreSQL.1st time i installed **postgreSQL** and then **PGAdmin** also.
- While installing i provided a password for default superuser "**postgres**" also.
- But i did not create any separate user with password.
- I also add the bin dir path in my *SYSTEM ENV PATH Variable*.
- When i tried My 1st command in CMD as ***>psql*** it prompted me as ***Password for user Krishu:***
- **Krishu** is my **System User** ,not my **postgre USER**. But It prompted me like that.Obviously I did not know the password .
- Later i try like this:
  [See this screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flydI.png)
- Later i searched in the internet and create a **user** named "**krishu**" same to what it showed before.
- But When i am trying login with [**upper case K** ] **Krishu** .It shows me USER doesn't exist. Later I see [**lowercase k**] **krishu** user is created ,even if i typed "**Krishu**" while creating USER.
- Actually I didn't understand why my prompt is always showing [**Password for user Krishu:**] *bydefault* when i type **[E:\Workspace\Python\homestaurant>psql]** in my **cmd**. What is the problem i couldn't understand.

Comment: If you don't specify a user, the OS user name is used by default. To create a PG account with an uppercase, it must be double-quoted ... but then you need to double-quote it to log-in, switch role etc as well!

Comment: Yes you are right.My OS  UserName is taken bydefault and that is the problem for me.What is the password for it? I tried using my OS user password,but no use,because i got same error <password authentication failed for user "Krishu">. I deployed an webApp in HEROKU and i am trying to connect my Heroku Postgres with my local Postgres .At that time also it ask me the password for that default User which i don't know.And thats why i am unable to connect .